# How to say "we will consider job applications also before the deadline"

Tags: expressions

I'm looking for a common phrase or at least a more elegant way to say something like the following:

> The deadline for this job application is end of April. But we will consider
>   applications before that deadline and may also already chose a
>   candidate beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

The deadline to accept applications is the end of April. We encourage applications as soon as you can submit them; we may choose a candidate before the deadline is reached.